# How can I split and select from an array of filenames in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a script I wrote in my company for clearing Citrix UPM profiles. Not very complicated, but it generates logs for every user it is run on. Along the format of:

UPMreset-e0155555-20150112-0733

UPMreset-n9978524-20150114-1128

UPMreset-jsmith-20150113-0840

etc.

So I want to grab the folder with all the .txt files, select only the username and count to see if one appears more than a certain number of times. To check for problem children. Putting them into an array is easy enough, but when doing a -split I can't seem to find a regex combination to select only the username. I thought I could just do a ('-')[1], but that doesn't appear to work. Do you have any suggestions?

```
$arrFiles = Get-Childitem "c:\logs"
$arrFiles | %{ $arrfile = $_ -split ('-'); Write-Host $arrfile[0]}
```

edit: Included test code for posterity sake.

Comment: Got my answer, but included the test code I used. It would only grab items before the hyphen. Adding [1] would output nothing. Is there a reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try something like this:

```
$Path = 'N:\Folder\*.txt';

Get-ChildItem $Path | 
    ForEach-Object {
        Write-Output $_.BaseName.Split('-')[1];
    } | 
    Group-Object | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -gt 1 } |
    Sort-Object -Property Name |
    Select-Object Name, Count;
```

---

To answer the question.

`$_` is one of the objects returned by `Get-ChildItem`.  Those objects are *not* strings.  They're .Net objects of type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` or `System.IO.FileInfo`.  That means if we use `$_`, we're referencing *the whole object*.  Worse, neither of those objects has a `Split()` method, so `$_.Split('-')` would refer to a function that didn't exist.

`BaseName` is a property of a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo object.  That property contains the name of the file without the path or the extension.  Critically, this property is also a String, which *does* have the `Split()` method.  So using this property does two things: It removes the path name and the extension since we don't care about that and we don't want it to potentially break something (e.g., if someone put a dash in the parent folder's name), and it gives us a String object which we can manipulate with String methods and do things like call the Split function.

Try something like this at the command line:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem 'N:\Folder\UPMreset-e0155555-20150112-0733.txt';
$x | Get-Member;
```

You'll get a huge list of Methods (functions) that the object can do and Properties (attribute values) of the object.  Name, FullName, BaseName, and Extension are all very common properties to use.  You should also see NoteProperties and CodeProperties, which are added by the PowerShell provider to make using them easier (they wouldn't be available in a C# program).  The definition tells you how to call the method or what the type of the property is and what you can do with it.  You can usually Google and find MSDN documentation for how to use them, although it's not always the easiest way to do things.

Compare the above to this:

```
$x.BaseName | Get-Member;
```

You can see that it's a String, that there all kinds of methods like Split, Replace, IndexOf, etc.

Another helpful one is:

```
$x | Select-Object *;
```

This returns all the Propety, NoteProperty, and CodeProperty values this object has.

This highlights one of the best ways to learn about what you can do with an object.  Pipe it to `Get-Member`, and you learn the type and any methods or properties that you can access.  That, combined with piping something to `Select-Object *`, can tell you a lot about what you're working with.

Comment: Multiple good answers, but this works perfectly for what I was trying. What does adding the BaseName to split change?

Answer (score 3):

What problem were you having with `.split('-')[1]`?

```
$filenames = @(
'UPMreset-e0155555-20150112-0733',
'UPMreset-n9978524-20150114-1128',
'UPMreset-jsmith-20150113-0840'
)

$filenames |% {$_.split('-')[1]}

e0155555
n9978524
jsmith
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the filenames are always `UPMreset-`, followed by the username. So use this:

`UPMreset-(.+?)-`

and the capture group will contain the username. It's using a lazy quantifier to get anything up to the next dash.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the split in a calculated property with Group-Object:

```
$FileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $LogDir -Filter "*.txt" -Name

$FileNames | Group-Object @{Expression={($_ -split "-")[1]}} | Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1}
```